# How to fix table columns overlapping in jspdf

Tags: php, pdf, jspdf

I am using jspdf plugin to generate pdf on my web page. But I am not getting table as i expected.I am getting output like this.
 [image]

How to get fix this and get the table correctly?

```
function HTMLtoPDF(){
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
source = $('#HTMLtoPDF')[0];
specialElementHandlers = {
    '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
        return true
    }
}
margins = {
    top: 50,
    left: 60,
    width: 545
  };
pdf.fromHTML(
    source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    , margins.left // x coord
    , margins.top // y coord
    , {
        'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
        , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },
    function (dispose) {
      // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF
      //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('Report.pdf');
      }
  )     
}
```

I am expecting to get output like this
[image]

Comment: How can we help you if you don't explain to us what you were expecting? Also, `width: 545` might give you clue.

Comment: @icecub why can't you edit to make the image visible

Comment: @SagarV I simply overlooked it. I'm (normally) not in the habit of editing someone's question just to see if something went wrong :)

Comment: use your privileges (wisely)

Comment: @SagarV I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for the tip. Anyway, I think the problem still lies within the width. It seems the result simply requires more width for the content to fit.

Comment: using this jspdf autotable plugin have solved the problem.Thank you every one.